# How do I maintain the on value with a lightswitch-field as a plugin setting?

Tags: field, plugin-development, lightswitch

I'm trying to use a lightswitch-field in a plugin-config. But for some reason it won't get saved. The lightswitch-field is always off.

```
protected function defineSettings()
{
    return array(
        ...
        'mailerShowInfo' => array(AttributeType::Bool, 'default' => false),
        ...
    );
}
```

_settings.html:

```
{{  forms.lightswitchField({
        label: "Show info in sidebar?"|t,
        id: 'mailerShowInfo',
        name: 'mailerShowInfo',
        value: settings.mailerShowInfo,
        required: true
    })
}}
```

I tried to use AttributeType::Number instead, and even used [settype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) in [prepSettings()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/plugin-settings) to force a boolean conversion, but still nothing.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you need to set the `on` value of your lightswitch field.

```
on: (settings.mailerShowInfo is defined) ? settings.mailerShowInfo : ""
```

So, the full settings of your twig code would be:

```
{{  forms.lightswitchField({
        label: "Show info in sidebar?"|t,
        id: 'mailerShowInfo',
        name: 'mailerShowInfo',
        value: settings.mailerShowInfo,
        required: true
        on: (settings.mailerShowInfo is defined) ? settings.mailerShowInfo : ""
    })
}}
```